# How to calculate standard deviation on fitted parameters from MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares

does anyone know how to calculate the standard deviation on the parameters obtained from maximum likelihood estimation assuming Gaussian noise? A lot of calculations I see involve either the Fisher information matrix or the Hessian. I know that the Fisher information matrix inverse really reveals the Cramer-Rao lower bounds, which is not the same as the variance. I believe the Hessian is just another way to calculate the Fisher information matrix, hence the same problem. Am I mistaken or does anyone know how to calculate the standard deviation on these parameters? A reference or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fisher information matrix gives the Cramer-Rao bound, but also the asymptotic variance of your estimator. Is your model a linear regression with Gaussian noise ?

Comment: yes, but I do not think I have enough points to necessarily achieve the asymptote

Comment: If your model is a linear regression with Gaussian errors, then your coefficients ML estimates are unbiased and follow a normal distribution with (not asymptotic) covariance the inverse of Fisher information matrix. Would this answer your question ?

Comment: This would but my model is not linear

Comment: Well depending on your model, the true variance-covariance matrix may or may not be computable explicitly. Can you give details about your model ?
An option if true covariance matrix is not available is to estimate it through bootstrap.

Comment: My model is something along the lines of $y=Aexp(-Bt-Ct^2)$ where A, B, and C are parameters to be estimated through MLE, where y is the measured signal and t is known (time)